# How can I center a shape/image within another shape in Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

For example, I have a rectangle, and I want to put an image of a duck in the very center of the rectangle, but I'm not sure how to align it properly without eyeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best and the only way is to drag it with mouse till it snaps to helping grid lines:

[image]